# Como calcular el valor de la columna total dado el valor de las otras columnas?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo un componente: (la w es de un framework personal pero funciona igual que una tabla de bootstrap b-table)

```
         <w-summary-table
          :items="items">
        </w-summary-table>
```

y en data tengo el listado armado sin calcular los valores sino que estan escritos:

```
items: [
        {message: 'SUBTOTAL', value: 100},
        {message: 'DESCUENTO', value: 20},
        {message: 'ENVÍO', value: 10},
        {message: 'IMPUESTO', value: 21},
        {message: 'TOTAL', value: 111}
      ]
```

pero tengo crear la funcion que traiga subtotal,descuento,envio,impuesto y total para poder generalizar esos datos ya que esta tabla corresponde a un listado de carritos abandonados de una web.

Los parametros en mi modelo de datos son:

> subtotal,discount,taxes,shipping,total.

Tambien cuento con price,quantity,summary.

**Como calcular el valor de la columna total dado el valor de las otras columnas?**

Comment: No termino de comprender bien tu pregunta. A que te referis con calcular?

Comment: @gbianchi ahi edité, lo que necesito es crear la funcion que traiga los valores de subtotal,discount,taxes,shipping,total.

Comment: Y para que queres tener eso en una funcion si esta en el data?

Comment: La pregunta no sera, como calcular el valor de la columna total? dado el valor de las otras columnas? y si es asi, falta que nos digas como es el calculo, y como haces para motrar columnas calculadas en tu modelo.

Comment: Y la formula sera subtotal - descuento + impuesto + envio?

Comment: @gbianchi te agradezco los comentarios, simplemente estoy un poco confundido por eso pido ayuda basado en las dudas que tengo. Si lo supiera realizar desde un principio, ya estaria.

Comment: Entiendo tu duda, lo que pasa es que tu pregunta resulto confusa desde el principio. Podes confirmar que esa es la formula para calcular el total?

Comment: si, esa seria la formula para calcular el total subtotal - descuento + impuesto + envio @gbianchi

Comment: Fijate que tu pregunta seria mas simple.. como agregar una columna calculada a una b-table, y das la formula, mostras un ejemplo de tu tabla con datos y si es posible un [mcve] de lo que tenes hasta ahora, y se arma todavia una solucion mas linda.

Answer (score 0):

Si como vos decis esto es una tabla como de bootstrap, entonces lo que necesitas hacer es una columna con un formato calculado.

Para ello, tenes que crear una columna particular (Yo siempre uso columnas declaradas).

En este caso, deberias declarar un array de columnas para que sepa que formato aplicar a cada una (en lugar de usar columnas por defecto):

La documentacion de b-table, en su parte [Formater Callback](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table) da una solucion para esto

```
data() {
  return {
    columnas: [
      {
        key: 'Total ',
        label: 'Total Calculado',
        formatter: (value, key, item) => {
          return item.subtotal - item.descuento + item.impuesto + item.envio;
        }
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! siempre tu ayuda es muy util. y me guió a la solución que adjunto debajo.

Answer (score 0):

lo solucioné incluyendo en mis computed con:

```
items () {
      return [
        {message: 'SUBTOTAL', value: this.cartSummary.products_amount},
        {message: 'DESCUENTO', value: this.cartSummary.discount.value},
        {message: 'ENVÍO', value: this.cartSummary.shipping_amount},
        {message: 'IMPUESTO', value: this.cartSummary.taxes.value},
        {message: 'TOTAL', value: this.cartSummary.final_amount}
      ]
    },
```

Donde value contiene los valores que me trae desde el servidor ya calculados.

Comment: No entiendo para nada tu solucion. Esas son variables computadas? y que contienen? si devolvers una sola linea, que sentido tiene hacer todo esto?